# using jQuery $(this).addClass not working, simple code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

this simple code is not working, just trying to add a class once clicked on.

```
    $('a').click(function(){    
      //alert('on'); WORKING
      $(this).addClass('on');
    })
```

The HTML is simply..

```
    <ul>
 <li><a href="">List Item 1</li>
 <li><a href="">List Item 2</li>
 <li><a href="">List Item 3</li>
 <li><a href="">List Item 4</li>                        
   </ul>
```

Comment: Add return false; inside click handler?

Comment: Do you have the jquery.js in the html file as resource?

Comment: Could also be missing the ready event: `$(function() { /* attach click event to dom elements here */ }`

Comment: yes, it's in the jQuery document.ready handler

Answer (score 5):

You didn't ever close your `<a>`, but it's working for me otherwise.

http://jsfiddle.net/L3nyE/

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>                        
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.on { background-color:red; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){    
      //alert('on'); WORKING
      $(this).addClass('on');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default behaviour

```
$('a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();    
  $(this).addClass('on');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, provided you either change the target of the links to `"#"`. (Or `return false` from the click handler.)

http://jsfiddle.net/jaNCq/1/

You never close your `<a>`'s but Firefox is smart enough to close them for you. Can't say for other browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code working fine, check so you load your code when the dom is loaded and ready.
[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FhSDX/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('a').click(function(){    
         $(this).addClass('on');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is Incorrect

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNgKt/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to close your "a" tags. Also add a ";" at the end of your jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the jquery lib referenced and wrap your code in the dom ready. This worked for me.

```
<style>
    .on{
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('a').click(function () {
            //alert('on'); WORKING
            $(this).addClass('on');
        })
    });
</script>
```